# Read and write xml with methods that taking parameters?

Tags: c#, xml

On my search, i have seen a lot of examples on reading and writing xml files. All of them has needs setting parameters or classes on every read and write process.

Is it possible to read and write on an XML file with subroutines that taking parameters as filename, node and function?

For example of a file named xmlExample :

```
<node0>
<node1><name>a</name><number>b</number>
<node2><name>aa</name><number>bb</number><extra>cc</extra>
<node3><another>aa</another><sample>bb</sample>


string filename = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\xmlExample .xml"
```

And then adressing the wanted object hierarchically:

```
Read( xmlExample, node0, node1 , name)
```

Or addressing that object with id-like unique node:

```
Read(xmlExample, sample)//there will be just one "sample".
```

My question is clearly about non-standart read and write approaches. Do we have to assign the unnecessary parts of file all the time or once a time we write to read or write functions, is it possible to call just function with parameters?

Comment: None of this makes sense. You should rethink your question.

Comment: "If possible, how can an xml file be read by just one function like Read(filename, node)?"

Comment: Sounds like you really just want something to construct an XPATH query?

Comment: It's not important in the method I will do as query or LINQ but I wonder if there is a way that gets this simple.

Comment: @ithnegique stop wondering and write a simple helper method.

Comment: I wrote. Please read above.

Comment: @ithnegique I don't see any code..

Comment: The wanted method is written above. If you have any ideas, you can write.

Comment: @ithnegique I say the same thing. Your comments implies you know XPath and LINQ. just fill the method body. That is all:) BTW: SO doesn't work that way: *you want a method and people write it for you..*

Comment: I used LINQ very rare so that question is about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32245/discussion-between-ithnegique-and-i4v)

Comment: @ithnegique The question is about *Write the code for me*. But SO expects *I wrote this code and am stuck in that part*.

Comment: The question is if you are able to help, please help. If you are not, SO doesn't contain just one question. The rest of site is for everyone.

Comment: So, you're asking for a method that works based on *the names of its parameters*? If you do, then I think that's a terrible idea.

Comment: @ithnegique If your question is `if I am able to help`, then the answer is yes. Will i do? No...

Comment: I didn't wonder this time, as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything ready made. However, you can quite easily create something like that. Take a look at [`XmlReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), and especially the [`XmlReader.ReadToFollowing` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for editing and commenting. I couldn't find and yes, probabyly I should write but maybe there is some ready library or something else.